# Get Password Value When Creating Account during WooCommerce Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, crm

I am connecting to an external CRM API where I am trying to create an account using the same username and password (that a customer creates when signing up on the checkout page) for both accounts.  It is possible to get the user password before it is hashed with Wordpress?

I am accessing all the other user order info that I need from WooCommerce and passing through the API to the CRM:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->billing_first_name;
$order->billing_last_name;
...
```

I only need the password un-hashed momentarily.  I've looked over the WC_Order documentation here: http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html and didn't see a good answer.

To be clear, I am not posting the un-hashed password to either database. WP is going to hash the PW and store it as it normally does. I am trying to create another account at the same time with the same username and password via the Neon API http://help.neoncrm.com/node/12.  I don't believe this is possible to do if the pw is already hashed by WP.

Comment: `"It is possible to get the user password before it is hashed with Wordpress?"` - I certainly hope not.  If so, that bug should be reported to WordPress immediately.  I suppose you *could* create your own form which accepts the user's password and then use that password for whatever purpose you want, but this is skirting a pretty fine line of responsible password handling.

Comment: I can get the password value from $_POST in the WooCommerce thankyou.php.  I was just hoping there was some less hacky way of doing this.

Comment: You should never, *ever* be able to see the user's unhashed password. Ever.

Comment: @Sippy I'm not sure what you mean by "be able to see the user's unhashed password."  It will only be stored unhashed for about the same amount of time WP has it unhashed.  Do you have a suggestion on how best to create two accounts like this at once?  I know it's probably not ideal, but I'm not sure how else to approach it.

Comment: @Sippy - maybe the question is unclear.  I'm not posting the un-hashed pw to any database.  WP is going to hash the PW and store it as it normally does.  I am trying to create another account at the same time with the same username and password via the Neon API.  I can't send a hashed password over that API or I wouldn't be able to log in, right? http://help.neoncrm.com/node/12

Comment: @Sippy - Also note that I do not believe WP using JavaScript to hash the passwords.  This occurs server side noted in their documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with a custom WooCommerce plugin that hooks into

```
'woocommerce_order_status_completed'
```

This filter needs to be triggered during the checkout phase because we are accessing the password field via $_POST during the checkout/account creation process.  To trigger this filter the order status needs to be updated to completed by using this filter:

```
'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status'
```

You can see the full method and filter here: http://www.rcorreia.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-automatically-set-order-status-payment-received/

Inside of the filter method in your plugin or theme for

```
'woocommerce_order_status_completed'
```

the account password can be passed to the Neon api by doing something like:

```
$accountPassword = sanitize_text_field($_POST['account_password']);
```

then passing the other user data request parameters with the password like:

```
array( ... 'individualAccount.login.password' => $accountPassword);
```

Comment: Have you find a less hacky way to achieve this rather than getting the plain text password from `$_POST['account_password']` ?

Comment: @elvismdev - I think this may actually work better.   Check out: function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) in the reference link below.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: This will not work if you for example use payment provider like eWay and it wants you to enter your creditcard number after checkout submit. The password form will get in the way and swallows up your $_post['account_password'].  I think you can better look for another hook that has something to do with user created

Comment: I looked in WC and found 'woocommerce_created_customer'. This hook will allow you to store the unhashed pw so that you can hash it into your own db.